# Twitter Api returns "code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data." by axios

Tags: javascript, twitter, axios, nuxt.js, twitterapi-python

I called this api by Python's requests.post like below.
[Twitter API](https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/basics/authentication/api-reference/request_token)

```
        headers = {'Authorization': 'OAuth oauth_timestamp="1615466796", oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_nonce="d31d6684-55ed-466d-8349-016bced6c94e", oauth_callback="https%2Fxxxxxx%2F%2Fxxxxxx%2F", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"'}

    return requests.post(url, headers=headers)
```

It works fine.
And I also want to call same api by axios like this.

```
 const response = await axios.post("/api/oauth/request_token",
            {
                headers: {
                    Authorization: 'OAuth oauth_timestamp="1615466796", oauth_consumer_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxx", oauth_nonce="d31d6684-55ed-466d-8349-016bced6c94e", oauth_callback="https%2Fxxxxxx%2F%2Fxxxxxx%2F", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature="xxxxxxxxxxxxx"'
                }
            }

        )
```

However I got this error.

```json
{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}
```

Does anyone know what the problem is ?

It's same Authentication header, so are there any syntax mistake on axios ?

※ I'm using @nuxtjs/proxy to avoid CORS error.

Here it's configuration of nuxt.config.js.

```
 proxy: {
    '/api/': { 
      target: 'https://api.twitter.com', 
      pathRewrite: {'^/api/': ''}
     }
  },
```

Comment: The parameter signature for `axios.post` is `url[, data[, config]]`, see https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config